# Check presence of an xml node if another xml node is present

Tags: powershell

I have a directory passed as a command line parameter to the power shell script . I need to recursively search for files with `csprj` extension and check whether `HintPath` node is  present under Project /ItemGroup/Reference node. If `HintPath` node is present, check the presence of another node named `Private` with value `False` and exit with error code 0. There could be multiple Reference nodes under ItemGroup

Is it possible to create a power shell script to do this? A sample xml file is given below

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
         ToolsVersion="3.5">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="IronPython, Version= ...">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\shared\IronPython-1.1\IronPython.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="log4net, Version= ...">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\binaries\log4net.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gci . -filter *.csproj -recurse | foreach-object {
  $filename = $_.fullname 
  [xml]$sample = gc $_.fullname
  $sample.Project.ItemGroup.Reference | 
  select @{N="filename";E={$filename}}, hintpath, private 
}
```

Should give you an overview like this:

```
filename                                 HintPath                                private
--------                                 --------                                -------
C:\users\mytest\desktop\sample1.csproj   ..\shared\IronPython-1.1\IronPython.dll        
C:\users\mytest\desktop\sample1.csproj   ..\binaries\log4net.dll                 False  
C:\users\mytest\desktop\sample2.csproj   ..\shared\IronPython-1.1\IronPython.dll        
C:\users\mytest\desktop\sample2.csproj   ..\binaries\log4net.dll                 False
```